# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event: error Unable to resolve the error

Tags: android

I am getting the following exception in my application...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event: class com.example.event.SelectedOptionsChangedEvent to handler [EventHandler public void com.example.activity.MainActivity.onSelectedOptionsChanged(com.example.event.SelectedOptionsChangedEvent)]Attempt to read from field 'int com.example.model.Option.id' on a null object reference

I am not able to resolve the error..please help..!

in the MainActivity i have a method :

```
 @Subscribe
    public void onSelectedOptionsChanged( SelectedOptionsChangedEvent optionsChanged )
    {
        if( Fragment != null )
        {
            Fragment.setSelectedOptions( AppController.getInstance().getSelectedOptions() );
        }
    }
```

I have a class :

```
public class SelectedOptionsChangedEvent
{

    public SelectedOptionsChangedEvent()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Just for checking remove this  if( Fragment != null )
        {
            Fragment.setSelectedOptions( AppController.getInstance().getSelectedOptions() );
        }
and make a toast their and tell me if it is showing you the toast

Comment: some thing wrong with AppController.getInstance().getSelectedOptions()

Comment: Fragment is a mapfragment and it checks whether mapfragment is null or nut

Comment: can you please do as I said ?

Comment: i have added the toast..and the toast is diaplayed